# Does this piece of code augment the input data?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network, data-augmentation

```
model=tf.keras.Sequential(
[
    Conv2D(filters=1, kernel_size=(3, 3), activation='relu', strides=1, padding='same'),    
    MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(4, 4)),
    
    Flatten(),
    Dense(6,activation="softmax")
    
])

model.compile(loss='CategoricalCrossentropy',
              optimizer='adam',
              metrics=['accuracy'])

train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(                                  # Real time data augmentation
        rescale=1./255,
        shear_range=0.2,
        zoom_range=0.2,
        horizontal_flip=True)

train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(            # Loads the File which contains the images.
        'train',                                                # Returns x (numpy array containing a batch of images)
        target_size=(150, 150),                                 # and correcponding labels
        class_mode='categorical')

model.fit( train_generator,
        batch_size=100,
        epochs=1)
```

The output of this code does not provide any information on the data augmentation. So could anyone clarify whether this code augments the available data?

Comment: train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(                                  # Real time data augmentation
        rescale=1./255,
        shear_range=0.2,
        zoom_range=0.2,
        horizontal_flip=True)

This augments the input data

Answer (score 0):

The code below augments the input images as you have written

```
train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(# Real time data augmentation
    rescale=1./255,
    shear_range=0.2,
    zoom_range=0.2,
    horizontal_flip=True)
```

However, there is no inbuilt way to test if data has been augmented or not. You can only inspect the result of the data to know if it's augmented or not and get any information you intend to get.

As an example, one way of knowing if the `rescale=1./255`  augmentation works is to print out the result of the `train_generator` to check if the values are between `0 - 1 (normalized)` or `0 - 255 (default)`.

```
image, label = next(train_generator) # return a single iteration batch
print(image.shape) #single batch list, if batch not specified (default is 32)
print(image[0].shape) # single image shape
print(image[0]) # single image output
```

you will get an output that looks like this

[image]

This shows that the resized image works, else you will get something like this

[image]

Which shows that the resized image does not apply.
I believe you can use a similar approach for other augmentations you intend to confirm